# How to detect C-style multidimensional arrays in templates specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20

I have the following code:

```
enum type_kind{unkown=-1,carray, multi_carray};

template<class T>
struct detect_carray{
   constexpr static int kind=unkown;
};
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct detect_carray<T[N]>{
   constexpr static int kind=carray;
};
```

Now, I want to add another specialization for detecting multidimensional arrays in C-style, that is, `T[a][b]...`.

What is the syntax to achieve this? Can I use Variadic templates?

I expect the following behavior:

```
int main()
{
std::cout<<detect_carray<std::vector<int>>::kind;//-1
std::cout<<detect_carray<int[3]>::kind;//0
std::cout<<detect_carray<double[3][5]>::kind;//1
std::cout<<detect_carray<std::complex<double>[3][5][8][16]>::kind;//1
//Correct out: -1011
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a specialization for multidimensional arrays:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
struct detect_carray<T[N1][N2]>{
   constexpr static int kind=multi_carray;
};
```

then

```
std::cout<<detect_carray<std::vector<int>>::kind;//-1
std::cout<<detect_carray<int[3]>::kind;//0
std::cout<<detect_carray<double[3][5]>::kind;//1
std::cout<<detect_carray<std::complex<double>[3][5][8][16]>::kind;//1
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BCOcyMwu3fSlBtcd)

BTW: For `double[3][5]`, `T` will be `double` (and `N1` will be `3` and `N2` will be `5`). For `std::complex<double>[3][5][8][16]`, `T` will be `std::complex<double> [8][16]` (and `N1` will be `3` and `N2` will be `5`).

Answer (score 5):

There's already a trait called [`std::rank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) in the standard library so the solution is quite simple:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct detect_carray {
  enum type_kind { unknown = -1, carray, multi_carray };

  static constexpr int kind = [] {
    switch (std::rank_v<T>) {
      case 0: return unknown;
      case 1: return carray;
      default: return multi_carray;
    }
  }();
};
```